# Warning popping up: preload-host-spawn-strategy Warning: waitpid override ignores groups

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, visual-studio-code

I am currently on Fedora Linux 38. I have installed VSCode and I have seen warning popping up again and again `[337 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups`

[image]

Even if I open Bash I cannot get login into my default user account. So my question is how can I login into user account from my shell account?

Comment: Some workarounds are listed [here](https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/370).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got this error when install VScode or Codium on Fedora 38 through software manager.

When I had manual installation though terminal means `sudo dnf install code` or `sudo dnf install codium`.

Comment: So what was your solution? “When I had manual installation though terminal means `sudo dnf install code` or `sudo dnf install codium`.”

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "login into my default user account", but you can get rid of the pesky warning by adding this to settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "LD_PRELOAD": null,
}
```

There is a [lengthy thread about the issue on github](https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/370).